# Nodejs Sending multiple files

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to send multiple files to a used and have them displayed, for now I'm testing with simple txt files.
Since piping more than 10 files at a time causes warnings/errors I have tried to only pipe 10 at a time. The function gets called the right amount of times but, for some reason, only sends part of the data ( always seems to stop at 2.3mb ). Any reason why?

```
  app.get('/file', function(req, res)  {
    console.time('leggo');
    var lowerbound = req.param('lowerbound'); // 3 vars used for the file.
    var upperbound = req.param('upperbound');
    var filename = req.param('filename');
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-type' : 'text/plain',
        'Content-disposition' : 'inline'
    });
    var readst = fs.createReadStream(base+ lowerbound + last); //first file.
    var count = 0; // number of files that are being sent atm.

    var add = function(i) { // add i'th file to the pipe
        console.log('whatevs');
        ++i;
        readst.push(base + i + last);
    };
    var started = 0;
    function sendem() { //send files.
        ++count;
        ++started;
        var mycallback = function () { //callback when doit finished
            console.log(count + ' ' + started + '\n');
            count -= 1;
            if (started == upperbound)
                return;
            if (count < 10) sendem();
        };
        function doit(mycallback) { //send a file then call callback
            add(started);
            mycallback();
        };
        doit(mycallback); //start sending.
}

    sendem(); // start the "main" sending function.
    readst.pipe(res); // pipe everything, also tried using this earlier, same effect.
    readst.on('end', function(err,data) { // "everything" was sent.
        console.log('done');
        console.timeEnd('leggo');
    });
});
```